# Is there a way to go from async code to sync for sequential execution

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, sequential

I'm trying to understand why i would need to use async all the way for a sequential execution on serverside of function with an original asynchronous call. (the is important to note, i'm speaking of sequential action)
I understand that when things don't go sequential it could be usefull to make things totally asynchronous, this way you don't block user.

Assume we have a function call and then we do a lot a of different operation depending on the last one, from the initial called data:

1. fct "0" call the data on server
2. fct "n" call and use the return of fct "n-1"

**Everything async : This is how i'm writing it actually using async await**

> async FctCall(path)-> async fct1(wait result of fctCall) -> aynsc fct2(wait Result of Fct1) -> etc

This way make the code a little more complexe and boring to write, and it don't seems to me to be logically needed.

**Only the call async : is there a way to write things this way ?**

> async FctCall(path)-> Wait until returned value -> end of async code -> fct1(result of fctCall) -> fct2(Result of Fct1) -> etc

Yes it will be blocking code, but as my code is purely sequential it's always the case. Fct2 needs the result of fct1 and so on.

I hope i have been clear (i tried to do my best). Let me know if my question is confusing

Comment: That's what I know as a waterfall model of async calls. Back before ES6, [async.js](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/) implemented waterfall async neatly, where the result of previous call is to be used for the next one, and so on.
However, we now have [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), and I believe that should do the job for you.

Comment: I am doing some major guesswork for interpreting your question, but it may be, that you are looking for https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await, which enables a syntactical return to sync, for "once only" initial async loads. Note, that it is moderately new, and doesn't have full support yet.

Comment: @choz Thank you very much, i will check this method

Comment: @ASDFGerte thank you for your answer and the link, i tried to do my best to be the clearest i could (i'm noob, i know it's not an excuse). You understood well the purpose of my question.

Answer (score 1):

You could write something like this

```js
async function foo() {
  let a = await k();
  let b = await z(a);
  let c = await gg(b);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's a more elegant solution than what i had for my code. It's now way more clear and simple to convert my code to node.js 
It was evident and i just don't thought about it.